# Three.JS - GLTF model loads slow. How to speed up load time?

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

Im loading a GLTF model (9mb) into ThreeJS. It's definitely loading slow. It takes about 4-5 seconds to load on my PC and about 11 seconds to load on my IPhone. How can i speed up the rendering times? My PC and IPhone load examples from the ThreeJS website faster than my project. My project has only one object being loaded so I feel like it should load faster than the examples on ThreeJS website.

My example project is located here @ http://flowolfsworld.com/

Code

```
var ourObj;
var ourObj2;

// Instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

// Optional: Provide a DRACOLoader instance to decode compressed mesh data
var dracoLoader = new THREE.DRACOLoader();
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath( '/js/draco/' );
loader.setDRACOLoader( dracoLoader );



let scene, camera, renderer, stars, starGeo;

function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,1000)
  camera.position.z = 25;

  //renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor("#000000");
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  starGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
  for(let i=0;i<6000;i++) {
    star = new THREE.Vector3(
      Math.random() * 600 - 300,
      Math.random() * 600 - 300,
      Math.random() * 600 - 300
    );
    star.velocity = 0;
    star.acceleration = 0.02;
    starGeo.vertices.push(star);
  }

  let sprite = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'star.png' );
  let starMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    color: 0xaaaaaa,
    size: 0.7,
    map: sprite
  });

  stars = new THREE.Points(starGeo,starMaterial);
  scene.add(stars);

 // window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
  var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
  hemiLight.position.set( 0, 300, 0 );
  scene.add( hemiLight );
  
  var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
  dirLight.position.set( 75, 300, -75 );
  scene.add( dirLight );



  loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'objs/dracowolf.gltf',
    // called when the resource is loaded
    function ( gltf ) {
  
      scene.add( gltf.scene );
      ourObj = gltf.scene;
      animate();
  
    },
    // called while loading is progressing
    function ( xhr ) {
  
      console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
  
    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function ( error ) {
  
      console.log( 'An error happened' );
  
    }
  );

  
}



function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }


  
function animate() {


  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  if(ourObj){
        ourObj.rotation.y -= .01;
    }
  starGeo.vertices.forEach(p => {
    p.velocity += p.acceleration
    p.y -= p.velocity;
    
    if (p.y < -200) {
      p.y = 200;
      p.velocity = 0;
    }
  });
  starGeo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  stars.rotation.y +=0.002;

}
init();
```

Comment: This is just the expected behavior for an object of such a large size. 9MB is a big file to download, and a lot of vertices to decode and send to GPU. The examples on Threejs.org load fast because they don't use 9MB files. You should look into using a normal map instead of such dense geometry, like [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=normal#webgl_decals)

Comment: See this website as an example: https://dogstudio.co/ Their `glb` file is only 840KB because instead of modeling the fur with real geometry, they used [this normal map](https://dogstudio.co/app/themes/portfolio-2018/static/assets/dog/images/dog/final/dog_normals.jpg) to save hundreds of thousands of vertices.

Answer (score 6):

A few suggestions on this particular model:

1. Use `.glb`, not `.gltf`. The binary form of glTF will be 25-30% smaller than a `.gltf` with embedded binary data, and doesn't have to be decoded from a Data URI. Using `.gltf` with a separate binary `.bin` is also an option. Use glTF-Pipeline to make these changes.
2. Preload the Draco decoder by calling `dracoLoader.preload()` before your model starts loading. On my test of your page, that would save 500ms spent fetching the decoder after the model has already been downloaded.
3. Consider using https://github.com/zeux/meshoptimizer#installing-gltfpack to simplify the model, or at least to quantize it, and then gzip it. This is an alternative to Draco, and may not compress the file quite as well, but can sometimes decrease overall loading time despite that.

Comment: Ok thanks you. The .glb model loaded way quicker. The previous model I used was gltf but i compressed it using "gltf-pipeline -i model.gltf -o modelDraco.gltf -d". It has a way smaller file size then the .glb file. Why is compressed .gltf version slower then the larger .glb file?

Comment: And given that I switched to suggestion #1, that means #2 doesnt apply right? Or could i compress my .glb file as well?

Comment: Hmm i spoke too soon. On my local machine it loads almost instantly but on the production version it still loads super slow on mobile. Almost worst then before.

Comment: When I dont use the compressed Draco .gltf file it doesnt render on mobile. The current state of the code is the same but with the .glb file and dracoLoader.preload() added. It load almost instantly on my localhost but doesnt load at all here on my mobile device @ http://flowolfsworld.com/

Comment: To your first comment — you can do both. `gltf-pipeline -i model.gltf -o modelDraco.glb -d -b`. To your later comments, I'm guessing the original size of this model is about 100MB?  The problem is that whole thing has to be decompressed — back to 100MB — before rendering. It's very detailed geometry with 3.5 million vertices, much more than you need for the app you're showing, so that's really slow. Tools like gltfpack should be able to simplify this to 10MB _before_ adding Draco compression, by reducing the number of vertices ~90%, and then Draco compression would make it even smaller.